AVPlayer Unexpectedly Auto-Pauses After Loading New Episode in macOS SwiftUI App
I'm developing a simplified macOS app using SwiftUI that plays podcast episodes using AVPlayer. Despite ensuring the app does not auto-play or auto-pause episodes, I'm encountering an issue where AVPlayer automatically pauses after loading a new episode.
Here's a simplified version of my logic for playing episodes:
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var playerViewModel = PlayerViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // UI for listing episodes
            List(playerViewModel.episodeURLs.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                Button(action: {
                    playerViewModel.loadEpisode(at: index)
                }) {
                    Text("Episode \(index + 1)")
                }
            }

            // Play/Pause button
            Button(action: playerViewModel.togglePlayPause) {
                Image(systemName: playerViewModel.isPlaying ? "pause.fill" : "play.fill")
            }
        }
    }
}

class PlayerViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var player = AVPlayer()
    @Published var isPlaying = false
    @Published var selectedEpisodeIndex: Int?
    private var playRequestedByUser = false

    let episodeURLs = [
        URL(string: ""https://traffic.libsyn.com/secure/skepticsguide/skepticast2024-04-06.mp3")!,
        URL(string: "https://traffic.libsyn.com/secure/skepticsguide/skepticast2024-03-30.mp3")!
    ]

    func loadEpisode(at index: Int) {
        // Logic to load and prepare an episode
        let item = AVPlayerItem(url: episodeURLs[index])
        player.replaceCurrentItem(with: item)
        player.pause()
        isPlaying = false
        playRequestedByUser = false
    }

    func togglePlayPause() {
        if isPlaying {
            pauseEpisode()
        } else {
            playRequestedByUser = true
            playEpisode()
        }
    }

    private func playEpisode() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            if self.playRequestedByUser {
                self.player.play()
                self.isPlaying = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func pauseEpisode() {
        player.pause()
        isPlaying = false
        playRequestedByUser = false
    }
}

Behavior Observed:

During playback, when a new episode is selected, the currently playing episode auto-pauses immediately, which is unintended. The expected behavior is for the app to wait for explicit user action to pause or play the selected episode.

Steps Taken:

Ensured that play and pause actions are only triggered by user interaction.
Implemented a flag to distinguish between user-initiated playback and system-initiated actions.
Added delays before playing an episode to avoid potential race conditions.
Isolated AVPlayer in a minimal setup to replicate the issue, confirming it persists in a simplified environment.

Question:
Has anyone experienced similar issues with AVPlayer on macOS apps developed with SwiftUI? What could be causing the immediate auto-pause upon selecting a new episode during playback, and how can I prevent this from happening?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

You say that when a user selects an episode, it's not intended that the current episode pauses, but inside your loadEpisode, you replace the contents of the player and explicitly pause it.

Thanks for your input. I've adjusted my loadEpisode method by removing player.pause(). Now, selecting a new episode auto-plays it, which wasn't intended. Here's the revised part:
func loadEpisode(at index: Int) {
    // Loading episode logic
    let url = episodeURLs[index]
    let item = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
    player.replaceCurrentItem(with: item)
    // player.pause() removed
    isPlaying = false
    playRequestedByUser = false  
}

Seeking advice to prevent auto-play and wait for user action.

You should edit your question, not try to use code in the comments section. My suggestion is that on item press, you store the index that was pressed. Then, on the press of the play button, call loadEpisode.

you'll need to remove the view model and the id: \.self to have any chance of getting valid SwiftUI code

Having a view model does not make it invalid SwiftUI code. And, with a static list, even the id: self works, although it isn’t the best practice.

@THEBONESMITH if you have an answer, you should leave it as an answer, not an edit to your original question.

I resolved the auto-pausing/playing issue by modifying the code to store the selected episode's index on selection, rather than immediately loading and playing the episode.
Here's an example of some code adjustments:
class PlayerViewModel: ObservableObject {

    func loadEpisodeWithoutPlaying(at index: Int) {
        guard episodes.indices.contains(index) else { return }
        let episode = episodes[index]
        let item = AVPlayerItem(url: episode.url)
        player.replaceCurrentItem(with: item)
        selectedEpisodeIndex = index
        isPlaying = false
    }

    func togglePlayPause() {
        guard let index = selectedEpisodeIndex, episodes.indices.contains(index) else { return }

        let selectedEpisodeURL = episodes[index].url
        if let currentAsset = player.currentItem?.asset as? AVURLAsset, currentAsset.url == selectedEpisodeURL {
            isPlaying ? player.pause() : player.play()
            isPlaying.toggle()
        } else {
            loadAndPlayEpisode(at: index)
        }
    }

    // The loadAndPlayEpisode and playEpisode methods ensure that
    // episodes are played only when explicitly requested by the user.
}

